# IBM PBM | Is there a way to return all service flows names in a list?

Tags: ibm-bpm

I want to add a tag name to all created service flow so I was searching on way to return all screvices names into a list to apply change on all of scervices at once but I got nothing.

-------------------------

Answer (score 0):

IBM BPM has Rest API for get resources.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/SS8JB4_19.x/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/rest/bpmrest/rest_bpm_wle_v1_assets_get.htm.

For example:
/rest/bpm/wle/v1/assets?processAppId=2066.55543795-75a5-46b0-be70-085f3ca4879b&snapshotId=2064.2a048759-2ffb-4cbe-bdcc-3cb5f928f4cd&branchId=2063.f0f87119-9769-404f-b93f-77571b1d0643&filter=type%3DService

also, you can try /bpmrest-ui/BPMRestAPITester/index.jsp to construct and try API requests to IBPM BPM